# Is high-speed sorting impossible with Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I've studied the poignant guide and it really has helped me pick up the
language pretty fast. After that, I started solving some coding puzzles
using Ruby. It just helps a lot to get used to the language I feel.

I'm stuck with one such puzzle. I have solved it very easily since it is
pretty straight-forward, but the solution is being rejected (by the host
website) with the error 'Time Exceded'! I know that Ruby cannot compete
with the speed of C/C++ but it has got to be able to answer a tiny puzzle on a website which accepts
solutions in Ruby?

The [puzzle](http://www.codechef.com/problems/TSORT/) is just a normal sort.

This is my solution

```
array ||= []
gets.to_i.times do
  array << gets
end
puts array.sort
```

My question is, is there any other way I can achieve high-speed sorting with Ruby? I'm using the basic `Array#sort` here, but is there a way to do it faster, even though it means lot more lines of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved that problem, and let me tell you using a `nlogn` algorithm to pass that is almost impossible unless you are using a very optimized C/Assembly version of it.

You need to explore other algorithms. *Hint: O(n) Algorithm will do the trick, even for ruby.*

Good Luck.

Comment: Have you solved the problem _in ruby_ with the O(n) algorithm you mention?

Comment: @Dogbert, Not me, i've solved it using C,Java, but after solving it i've had access to all the submitted solution. And here's one [Ruby Solution](http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/739964) (Note: It's visible only to people who solved the problem)...It take 9.87 Seconds (but Scripting languages are given a higher time limit than HLL, so it'll pass the submission).

Comment: Not sure about that time limit: I have ported the C# solution from the puzzle page to Ruby (http://ideone.com/SudcW), it's working below 5s on my machine (Core 2 Duo) for 1000000 numbers, but it doesn't pass the submission.

Answer (score 1):

You're sorting strings when you should be sorting ints. Try:

```
array << gets.to_i
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no need for duplicate values to be repeated:

```
h = {}
gets.to_i.times{h[gets.to_i] = true}
(0..100000).each{|n| puts(n) if h[n]}
```

If duplicate values must be repeated:

```
h = Hash.new(0)
gets.to_i.times{h[gets.to_i] += 1}
(0..100000).each{|n| h[n].times{puts(n)}}
```

Comment: @st0le I thought the question was expecting that, but I updated my answer to accomodate your point.